# Why does my change button not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am quite new to javascript and I am learning more about HTML5, Javascript and CCS3.

The task I have been given:

Create a chess board where you use JavaScript to write the cells (8x8), and then use nth-child to change the background color in CSS.

As you can see I have done that, I don’t know if I have done it in a good way, but I am now going to add a button that change the sides (black and white side). I have tried to solve it by creating var with boolean value, if it’s true it will load one function, and if it’s  false another. It works in loading the page, but the change button does not work. What have I done wrong?

[image]

HTML and JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ccsO2.css">



    </head>
<body>

<h1>Sjakkbrett</h1>

<script>

    var truefalse = true;

    function changer(){
        if(truefalse === true){
            truefalse = false;
        } else{
        truefalse = true;
    }
    }

    var svartbrikke = new Array();
    svartbrikke [0] = "&#9820";
    svartbrikke [1] = "&#9822";
    svartbrikke [2] = "&#9821";
    svartbrikke [3] = "&#9819";
    svartbrikke [4] = "&#9818";
    svartbrikke [5] = "&#9821";
    svartbrikke [6] = "&#9822";
    svartbrikke [7] = "&#9820";
    svartbrikke [8] = "&#9823";

    var hvitbrikke = new Array();
    hvitbrikke [0] = "&#9814";
    hvitbrikke [1] = "&#9816";
    hvitbrikke [2] = "&#9815";
    hvitbrikke [3] = "&#9813";
    hvitbrikke [4] = "&#9812";
    hvitbrikke [5] = "&#9815";
    hvitbrikke [6] = "&#9816";
    hvitbrikke [7] = "&#9814";
    hvitbrikke [8] = "&#9817";

    if(truefalse === true){

    document.write('<table>');
    for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){

            document.write('<tr align="center">');
        for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){

            if(i === 0){
                document.write('<td>' + svartbrikke[j] + '</td>');
            }
            if(i === 1){
                document.write('<td>' + svartbrikke[8] + '</td>');
            }
            if(i === 6){
                document.write('<td>' + hvitbrikke[8] + '</td>');
            }
            if(i === 7){
                document.write('<td>' + hvitbrikke[7 - j] + '</td>');
            } 
            else if(i >= 2 && i <= 5) {
            document.write('<td> </td>');
            }
        }
        document.write('</tr>');
    }
    document.write('</table>');
    } else {

    document.write('<table>');
    for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){

            document.write('<tr align="center">');
        for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){

            if(i === 0){
                document.write('<td>' + hvitbrikke[j] + '</td>');
            }
            if(i === 1){
                document.write('<td>' + hvitbrikke[8] + '</td>');
            }
            if(i === 6){
                document.write('<td>' + svartbrikke[8] + '</td>');
            }
            if(i === 7){
                document.write('<td>' + svartbrikke[7 - j] + '</td>');
            } 
            else if(i >= 2 && i <= 5) {
            document.write('<td> </td>');
            }
        }
        document.write('</tr>');
    }
    document.write('</table>');
    }


</script>
<button onclick="changer();"> Bytt side</button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
root { 
    display: block;
}

table{
    background-color: lightgray;


}



tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td:nth-child(2n){
    content: center;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;



}

tr:nth-child(2n) > td:nth-child(2n+1){
    content: center;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use [document.write()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp) after the page is rendered.

Use:

- [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

or

- [DOM methods](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

to change/add/remove page elements after the page is rendered.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have now used innerHTML, created the sides as two function and a third function to do the calling for each function. The problem is that when I press the button, the new board can't load canvas (other than that the sides have changed), and if I press it again a new board appears under the old.

Comment: I have solved it. Did not work with document.writer at all. So I saved the values to a var and returned that.

Answer (score 0):

You change the variable, but the code that checks it has already run and you don't rerun it.